# Removing entries with missing links

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Number 1:

```
adresse
  id    name
```

Number 2:

```
produkte
  id    anbieter
```

Details:

```
id: int
name: string
anbieter: int
```

Each anbieter in produkte is to be an id in adresse. For example:

```
adresse
  id  name
  1   hello
  2   there

produkte
  id  anbieter    
  1   1
  2   1
  3   2
  4   1
```

Works, but

```
adresse
  id  name
  1   hello
  2   there

produkte
  id  anbieter    
  1   4
  2   1
  3   2
  4   1
```

doesn't because there is no adresse.id of produkte.anbieter = 4

My goal is to remove every entry of produkte whose anbieter does not have an adresse.id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query: Delete a entry which is not present in a join table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620292/sql-query-delete-a-entry-which-is-not-present-in-a-join-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN to find rows that don't have a match and delete them.

```
DELETE produkte.*
FROM produkte
LEFT JOIN adresse
ON produkte.anbieter = adresse.id
WHERE adresse.id IS NULL
```

`LEFT JOIN` is like `INNER JOIN`, except when there's a row in the left table (`produkte`) that has no rows in the right table (`adresse`) that match the `ON` condition. INNER JOIN would leave the row out of the result, `LEFT JOIN` returns a row with `NULL` in all the right table's columns.  You can then use `WHERE <right-table>.<column> = NULL` to find the rows that had no match.

For more explanation about the different types of joins, see:

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)